# Moving custom list artifacts from DEV to PROD

Tags: 2013, list, move

In an On-premises SharePoint 2013 Enterprise Farm, would like to move custom list artifacts from DEV to PROD given the followings:

1. The list with contents already exists in **PROD**
2. In **DEV**, using Designer, the same list has been recreated and few new fields/columns have been added
3. In **DEV**, using Designer, the Display, Edit, and New forms have been customized with added JQuery and CSS

**Question**: What would be the recommended way to move the customized artifacts from DEV to PROD keeping the content of the list in PROD intact, and without using any third-party tool?

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case we need to use any of the third party tools like sharegate, Metalogix etc. Don't worry about the licensing, you can use the trial version.

Using the third-party tool, need to perform the **delta/incremental** migration, however, before the migration you need to create the additional columns in the prod those are not available in the prod but available in dev.

And after the incremental migration, you need open the target list from prod in the SharePoint designer and copy paste the customization (js, css) from dev list.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Habibur!